# Программная смена android:src

Tags: java, android

Мне приходит определенная цифра и исходя из этой цифры я меняю картинку, но при смене мне вылетает вот такая ошибка

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xada64ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: ru.httpinsideonline.yocapital, PID: 1341
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at ru.httpinsideonline.yocapital.MainActivity$44.onClick(MainActivity.java:3589)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

вот пример кода:

```
switch (mSettingsVal) {
            case 1:
                icoValScheta.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rouble_white));
            break;
            case 2:
                icoValScheta.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baks_white));
            break;
            case 3:
                icoValScheta.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.euro_white));
            break;
            default:
                icoValScheta.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baks_white));
            break;
        }
```

Comment: У Вас указатель на MainActivity.java:3589, вот там и смотрите.

Comment: @Hombre Я там и смотрел, но это строка, это "icoValScheta.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rouble_white));" и я не вижу здесь ошибки

Comment: icoValScheta случаем не null? Присвоение view выполнено перед сменой изображения?

Comment: icoValScheta это ImageView и оно присвоено, до этого когда проблема в том, что именно здесь происходит ошибка, но я не могу понять в чем причина

Comment: Проверьте чему равен icoValScheta, быть может Вы id не того layout'а указали, при присвоении указателя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно icoValScheta оказался null. Пришлось определять его дважды 1 раз до обработчика нажатия кнопки в onCreate, и еще один раз в обработчике нажатия этой самой кнопки прям перед сменой.

Comment: Проблема видимо в том, что внутри анонимного класса не может быть внешних не final переменных. Укажите при первой инициализации, что переменная final: `final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)`/ Если обработчик не в методе `onCreate()`, то пришла пора узнать о полях класса.  Из всего этого следует, что ваше решение - костыль и его надо решать дальше. В вопросе нужно больше когда - где происходит инициализация переменной и тд.